# Passing functions between REACT components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

I am building a REACT app which will show some recommendations for various restaurants. 
The main component has two handlers called 
1. handleLiked

```
handleLiked = () => {
    console.log("in like");
}
```

2. handleDisliked

```
handleDisliked = () => {
        console.log("in like");
    }
```

I pass the state and these two handlers from `MainComponent.js` to `Listings.js`

```
<Listings listings={this.state.listings} city={this.state.selectedCity} likedCounter={this.handleLiked} dislikedCounter={this.handleDisliked}/>
```

Listings.js is a functional component and I receive props. 
if I console.log(props) 
I can see the handlers.

From Listings.js I run a loop on the records in the state and pass the data to a child component called Listing.js. I have a for loop which generates the following call to the child component called Listing.

```
            return <Listing 
            key={listing.key} 
            listingTitle={listing.listingTitle} 
            listingCity={listing.listingCity} 
            listingBodyText={listing.listingBodyText}
            listingLikes={listing.likes}
            listingDislikes={listing.dislikes} 
            listingLikesHandler={listing.likedCounter}
            listingDislikesHandler={listing.dislikedCounter}
            />
```

When I receive props in Listing.js, I can see all the properties such as city, bodytext etc. but the handlers become undefined. Can you please help me understand how to pass these to the Listing component in my example.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass the handlers from the `listings` object, whereas the handlers are each passed as their own object in the props for the `Listings` component. Change `listing.likedCounter` to `props.likedCounter` and the same for the dislike handler and it should work fine.

Comment: please add whole code from listing.js file

Comment: @Rodentman87 cannot believe I did that mistake, thanks a ton for spotting it out. Your reply solved it for me.